# SQL query to group by status and show count for each status seperately

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

```
ID  Name   Status      Mode
1   Test1  Processed   Mode A
2   Test2  In-Flight   Mode B
3   Test3  Processed   Mode B
4   Test4  In-Flight   Mode A
5   Test5  Processed   Mode A
```

Please help to build a query that will return

```
Mode    Processed In-Flight
Mode A  2         1
Mode B  1         1
```

Got the answer but now I am in confusion how to execute this query in spring boot app which connects to PostgreSQL
I am using crud repository

Answer (score 0):

You can use filtered aggregation for that:

```
select mode, 
       count(*) filter (where status = 'Processed') as processed,
       count(*) filter (where status = 'In-Flight') as in_flight
from the_table
group by mode
order by mode;
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the status value ,Is there any way to make it dynamic by using 
Select distinct status from table and iterate through that result and add them in condition

Comment: @Abhi: no, the number, names and data types of the columns of a SELECT statement must be known/defined _before_ the query is executed. One workaround might be to aggregate into a JSON value as described e.g. [here](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/pivot-alternatives/)

Comment: I had tried a lot and failed to find a way to implement query in my spring boot app which uses crud repository and postgreSQL.
Can you help me in that as well.
@a_horse_with_no_name